# Open report link URL in new window in SSRS does not work

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services

I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services in SharePoint 2010 integrated mode. I am trying to set the action (navigation) for a text box to go to a URL and open an new window and ultimately pass a parameter to it. However, I am not even able to open a simple URL in a new window. This is what I have been trying for the expression:

=javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.ca','_blank'))

My report is accessed in a **PerformacePoint dashboard**. (If I open the report directly in SharePoint and click on the link it works fine and a new window opens. The problem only exists when the report is hosted in a dashboard page.)

When I click on it nothing happens even though it is clickable. When I hover over it, it shows javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.ca','_blank'))

Thanks,
Ali

Answer (score 2):

```
="javascript:void(window.open('http://www.google.ca','_blank'))"
```

Put that script in quotes - it worked for me.